# dell inspiron 15 3552 ubuntu 18.04 lts installation

Tags: 18.04

I'm trying to install ubuntu 18.04 lts on my laptop dell inspiron 15 3552. It's in the list of the supported devices. I create a bootable usb using the "Startup disk creator" but when I load from this usb I see the menu with the point "install ubuntu". I click on it and then get nothing but a black screen. Could you please point me ti the right direction? What's the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you installing in UEFI or BIOS boot mode. It should be new enough to be UEFI? Is Windows installed or bland drive? Post this from live installer: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: While booting I'm just pressing F12 and choose USB stick from the list. Not sure whether I install in UEFI mode or not. How to check this out? But I have UEFI on the laptop, yes.

Comment: Windows requires gpt for UEFI or MBR(msdos) for BIOS. So parted output will show type of install. To ascertain the type of Platform Firmware on a Windows 8 computer, open Run ( WinKey+ R ), type "msinfo32" and click OK. Should show mode.

Comment: I have ubuntu 14.04 lts installed and not windows there. but anyway thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very similar question like mine, I have a similar laptop, in my case, is a Dell Inspiron 15 5000 with the same problem. First, check if you have disabled the fast boot in the BIOS and then follow my answer in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030717/install-ubuntu-18-04-lts-on-dell-inspiron-15-5000/1031174#1031174).